# Associate Multiple IPs to a EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip, amazon-vpc

I have learned that one can associate multiple IP address to an instance in Amazon VPC. My question now is, I run an application (CLI based script which sends HTTP requests) on the instance and want to know from which IP address will the request be sent. Is there any way I can control the outbound IP address, i.e. the outbound requests from the script are sent from a particular IP only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind your application to a certain IP address. This is the same method as with any conventional multi-interface machine. The method of binding depends on your application and programming language (if you need help, StackOverflow would be your best bet).

Comment: Thanks for guiding. I will be using wget or curl requests and it can done by passing arguments like --bind-address or --interface